# TimeDistributed in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to implement a simple many to many LSTM for Sequence Prediction. The problem is very easy. The input is a sequence of 0s and 1s. The output at each time step is the count of ones in the sequence until that time step. For example assume the input is [0 1 0 1]. The output of the given input would be time0=0, time1=1, time2=1, time3=2. I should note that I use One hot encoding to represent the output.

Assumptions: the length of the input sequence is 20 (so at most I can have 20 ones in the sequence). Therefore, I consider 21 classes for output (one hot encoding). Class 0 means there is no one in the sequence. Class 21 shows that we have 20 ones in the sequence.

So far, I use the following model:

```
# create LSTM

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(30, input_shape=(20, 1), return_sequences=True ))
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(30, input_shape=(20, 1)))
print (model.input_shape)
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

#model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(21, activation='softmax')))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(21, activation='softmax'))


print(model.summary())


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer='adam',
             metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I evaluated it by adding and removing "tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed". Both of them reach the same accuracy of 99%! I am wondering why is that? So when we need to use "TimeDistributed"? What is it for then?

Answer (score 6):

For `Dense` layer you don't have to use `TimeDistributed` because the kernel gets [broadcasted](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting). For example you have `(30, 21)` as your W and `(batch, 20, 30)` as your x, so when you multiply the kernal gets broadcasted multiplied with every minibatch entry and you end up with (batch, 20, 30) times (30, 21) gives you `(batch, 20, 21)`. The equation is `Wx` here.

You use `TimeDistributed` when you have more complicated layer or even a model. Imagine a CNN model which you want to apply to every frame of the video. Then you could `TimeDistributed` to it's full potential.